# How to solve this integral using only power series?

Tags: definite-integrals, power-series

How can I integrate:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^{3}}dx$$

Using only power series.

What I did so far:

I thought using the geometric series sum: $$S = \frac{1}{1-(-x^3)}$$, which gives to me the power series: $$\frac{1}{1-(-x^3)} = 1-x^3+x^6...$$

And I integrated: $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^{3}}dx = x-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^7}{7}...$$

And now, the lower limit will be 0, and the upper limit will be the series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1}$$

Which seens to converge, by the alternanting series test. But, for what vallue? How can I continue from here??

If there's any mistake that I didn't noticed in my try so far, or if I'm taking the "hard way" to the solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You did not make any mistake! There is another trick you can do before evaluating the two limits of the integral. Instead, try to see if you can massage the indefinite integral $x-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$ into another closed form expression.

Specifically, I'm thinking about terms with logarithms and arctans. We know that
$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$$ and $$\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\cdots.$$ If you take a linear combination of two logarithms and one arctan, with appropriate modifications of the functions inside of their arguments [i.e., you can consider things like $\log(x^2+3x+1)$], you can express the indefinite integral in closed form. Then you'll be able to evaluate the two limits of the integral more easily!

This may not be easy... but it does work.